# ValueError when executed in separate thread

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a function that processes a zip file of csvs in my Django application. I call the function after a button press when rendering the view by creating a new thread and sending the function as the run method. Here is the function I want to call:

**update_db.py**

```
def upload_files(csv_files):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    for csv_filename in csv_files.namelist():
        if csv_filename.endswith('.csv'):
            csv_file = csv_files.open(csv_filename)

            # extract team name from csv_file string, remove whitespace
            table_name = csv_filename.rsplit('/',2)[1]
            table_name = re.sub('[^\w+]', '', table_name)

            try:
                df = pandas.read_csv(csv_file, error_bad_lines=False)
                df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

                ##do some stuff

            except pandas.errors.EmptyDataError as ex:
                print(str(csv_file) + ' was empty; continuing...')
                continue;

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

The problem is that the function runs perfectly fine if I call it in views, but if I try passing it to a thread it doesn't. This is what I have in the calling environment:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        if str(myfile.name).endswith('.zip'):

            unzipped = zipfile.ZipFile(myfile)
            # If I uncomment this line, it doesn't throw an error
            #upload_files(unzipped)


            # When these lines execute, I get an error
            t = threading.Thread(target = upload_files, args = (unzipped, ))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

            return render(request, 'webapp/upload.html', {
                'success': True
            })
    return render(request, 'webapp/upload.html', {
        'success': False
    })
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/0xDEADBEEF_Football/football/webapp/scripts/update_db.py", line 19, in upload_files
    csv_file = csv_files.open(csv_filename)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1368, in open
    fheader = zef_file.read(sizeFileHeader)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 705, in read
    self._file.seek(self._pos)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: seek of closed file
```

Why does running the function in a separate thread cause an error and what is the best way to fix the issue?

Comment: First, why don't you do the `unzipped = zipfile.ZipFile(myfile)`  inside `upload_files`, so you can just pass it a filename instead of a `ZipFile` object, and you can be guaranteed that it keeps the `ZipFile` object alive for the entire time?

Comment: Second, why are you using `daemon=True`? The only thing this means is that the process can exit while that thread is still running. Which means files you thought you uploaded may have been silently canceled. I don't know if it's related to this error or not, but it's probably not a good thing.

Comment: Finally, this is a perfect case for a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` or `multiprocessing.Pool`. That gives you a single convenient thing to wait on or gracefully cancel (the executor/pool) at shutdown time, and it means that if you get a burst of uploads you still only try to handle N of them at a time instead of spawning dozens of threads, and so on.

Comment: The function takes a long time to execute which is why we want it in a separate thread to begin with (otherwise the gateway times out when rendering the view). We don't want the rendering thread to wait on the execution which is why we set it as a daemon. We have code that notifies the user whether the process completed successfully or not depending on exceptions. Your first suggestion is a good point and I made those changes but that doesn't alleviate the issue.

Comment: Taking away `daemon=True` won’t make the rendering thread wait on it to finish. It’ll just make the _process as a whole_ wait on it to finish. In other words, it’ll make it impossible to accidentally shut down with half-finished executions. And that’s the only thing it will do. (But again, I think you really want a pool here. That’ll make it easy to implement a graceful shutdown.)

Comment: Duly noted, thanks for the explanation. I'll look into switching the a pool soon but I'd still like to have some clarity / possible solution on what is causing the problem right now as it is (aka why the thread affects the successful completion of the function).

Comment: First, is the process actually exiting? Depending on your WSGI setup, it could be creating new Django processes. It could even be creating one per request, and then exiting as soon as the you finish rendering the request. This means any daemon threads will get killed—and they may raise an exception which (depending on how your WSGI server works) may get traced to your logs, even though it doesn't affect the main process.